# Excel VBA for loop formula with relative cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to start in cell "B2", put in a formula that takes the cell to the left of "B2", which is "A2", multiplied by a number on another sheet..

My problem is...how do I reference the cell to the left? And also, how do I reference the cell on the other sheet? I am pretty sure it will be the same answer, but I can't figure it out..

```
Sub RelFormula()

For Col = 1 To 2
    For Row = 2 To 6
        Cells(Row, Col).Formula = "=" & Cells.Offset(0, -1).Value & "*" worksheets("output").range("A1")
    Next Row
Next Col

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing an ampersand after the quoted asterisk.

Comment: that was a typo when asking the question, I have the ampersand in my code and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's never a good idea to use a variable with a name that duplicates a *reserved word*; in this case `Row`.

Comment: There are at least two problems with `Cells.Offset(0, -1).Value`. a) `Cells` in this context refers to every cell on the worksheet and you cannot select a range that is one column to the left of the entire worksheet. b) If you meant `Cells(r, c).Offset(0, -1).Value` then you are starting the *c* loop at *1* and there is no column *0*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `offset`, you can just -1 from the column argument of `Cells`. You also missed off the row and column argument of `Cells` used in the formula, the final `&`, as comments pointed out.

Also, its a really bad idea using keywords, or reserved words as variables. Some names are protected, and VBA will simply not compile/run if certain words are used as variables names - but for things like "Row", which are used in other places in VBA...it is asking for trouble (i.e. not recommended/bad practice, etc), and will be confusing to read/debug, etc.

Also, consider using `Option Explicit` (if you are not already) at the top of any code module. This will make VBA complain/stop if you do not define *all* of your variables. It can be frustrating for beginners - but it is worth it in the long run.

I've rewritten your code, superficially, renaming and defining variables. Technically you do not need the double (outer) loop (`c_loop` takes just one value):

```
Sub RelFormula()

Dim r_loop, c_loop As Integer

For c_loop = 2 To 2

    For r_loop = 2 To 6

        Cells(r_loop, c_loop).Formula = "=" & Cells(r_loop, c_loop - 1).Value _
        & "*" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    Next r_loop

Next c_loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Good catch on all fronts!

Comment: @Brian - `Option Explicit` can be made automatic to all code sheets with Tools ► Options ► Editor ► Require variable declaration.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help, this is great! I am new to VBA and still learning, so any and all pointers help a lot